# Change custom UITableViewCell height based on view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` I've created programmatically that I want to be the full height of my view. I've overridden "`heightForRow`", but that doesn't affect the size of the cell's frame on the first load. The current frame loads at **320 width**, **44 height** which I guess is the default size for a cell. The frame of the cell does not change until I actually scroll the cell off screen then back on to "refresh" it. What should I do to set the cell's frame height to be full screen on the first load?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Please add code. The "heightForRow" is called from the first time the tableView is loaded. If you need to scroll and scroll back to see the size change, you are doing something wrong. And are you trying to calculate the cell size progrematicly?  (Meaning no AutoLayout), if you are trying to use auto layout, you are not using the right function.. So please past your code (:

Comment: As suggested by @PiratM, pls add code.

Answer (score 0):

Reload tableview in viewDidAppear. Best way to handle these kind of scenarios is making cell through xib or storyboard and applying auto layout constraints.